# How to get a audio file's duration time in Mathematica?

Tags: import, java, sound, automation

I have a *.avi file and if I want to know the file's **duration time**:
I can use this code to get the result:

```
Import["test.avi", "Duration"]
```

or the code to get the same result

```
(Import["test.avi", #] & /@{"FrameCount","FrameRate"}) /. {a_, b_} -> a/b
```

But if I want to know the duration time of a **audio file**,I try to use the similar code,but failed.

you can see the result don't involve the ***Duration***

```
Import["test.mp3","Elements"](*only version10 supports MP3 format*)
```

> {"AudioChannels", "Data", "SampledSoundList", "SampleRate", "Sound"}

Can I get the duration of audio files?

I guess the *Jlink`* can do this job easily...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239350/how-to-extract-duration-time-from-ffmpeg-output            In linux,this way can be done.But I use windows,dose the mathematica runs Run function to do the same job?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jd3lib/?source=recommended or http://sourceforge.net/projects/javamusictag/ or http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/  do some helps to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now,in Mathematica 11.
Using `Duration` function make it more easily:

```
Import["ExampleData/car.mp3", "Duration"]
```

Or

```
Duration@Audio["ExampleData/car.mp3"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the duration by counting the number of samples, and dividing by the sampling rate. For example, importing the stereo file="soundfile.wav"

```
sr = Import[file, "SampleRate"];
{channels, samples} = Dimensions[Import[file, "Data"]];
duration = samples/sr // N
```

Comment: But it's very slow,if a audio file is too large,it can't stored in the memory.

Comment: the way may make the mma throws a SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure",...],the code is:  i = FileNames["E:\\ipod\\*.mp3"];data = Table[snd = Import[file];
   sr = snd[[1, 2]];
   {chan, samples} = Dimensions[snd[[1, 1]]];
   {samples/sr // N, MemoryInUse[]}, {file, Take[i, 20]}];

Comment: If you get memory errors, then don't load all the files into memory at once!